# Topology of Time

Tags: spacetime, resource-recommendations, time, causality, topology

I came across the concept of topology of time and causality in Reichenbach book, "Philosophy of Space and Time". It would be nice to have list of references of recent developments of the same. It could be textbooks, research papers or published articles.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the book referred is by a philosopher. the question should go to https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-science

Comment: Yes, it's philosophy but references may be physics papers/books. Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_topology and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251867/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/763407/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257665/226902

Comment: @annav Yes, Reichenbach was a philosopher, but "He was literate in the physical science of his time, and acquainted with many of its most eminent practitioners. Criticism and justification of scientific methodology formed the core of almost all his philosophical efforts" https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reichenbach/ Eg, he made important contributions regarding the conventionality of clock synchronisation in Special Relativity, see https://sites.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/significance_conv_sim/index.html#epsilon

Answer (score 1):

One nice book about the meaning of time from a physicist's point of view is
Sean Carroll's [From Eternity to Here: The Quest for the Ultimate Theory of Time](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6371455-from-eternity-to-here). It discusses almost every concievable angle of the physical and philosophical meaning of time, including why it seems to "flow" forward, whether it flows the same everywhere, whether there is one flow of time or a multiverse of different options, whether you could have a "loop" of time instead of a straight line, and a lot more.